# Intellisense help VC++ 9

Tags: visual-c++

I'm new to c++. I'm using visual studio professional. I'm using Allegro library to make a game. When I access an Allegro type or an std; type, intelisense shows me the members. for instance if I do buffer-> it brings up a rectangle listbox of all the class members. But when they are my types it does not work.

I made a struct called PLAYER

```
struct PLAYER{
int age;
int health;
bool isdead;
};
```

so then I expected that if I did:

```
PLAYER *player;
```

player.

that I would see the members.
I tried :: , . , and -> but none work.
Where am I going wrong? 
If I do player.health = 100;
it compiles but intellisense doesnt pick up on it.

Thanks

Comment: player.health = 100; can not compile..you should use player->health = 100; You are not getting for -> also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intellisence need to add your types in its database (file [YourSolution].ncb). Sometimes Intellisence can not add them so you need to:

1. Close Visual Studio,
2. Delete the .ncb file near to your solution file (.sln) cause your problem may be due to a corrupted file,
3. Re-start Visual Studio. Intellisense will take some times to recreate all its database. Those time your type should be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

close and then reopen your VS, then try again.